# how can I find the max length word in the file?

Tags: python, dataframe

I did a scrape on a ps4 games website, when I scraped the product name which will be the game name under the variable product_name and the shipping prices under the variable price, and I saved it in 'dataframe.cvs' file. How can I print out the games with the longest names from the dataframe.cvs. I'm not looking for the shipping prices but for the name of the games.

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
import re

url='https://www.newegg.com/PS4-Video-Games/SubCategory/ID-3141'

with uReq(url) as uClient:
    page = uClient.read()

# parsing
page_soup = soup(page, "html.parser")

# grabs products
containers= page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item-container"})

# save to file
filename = "products.csv"


#creating two empty dictionaries
d = defaultdict(list)
d1 = defaultdict(list)

# for loop fills dicts
for container in containers:
   #scrape the brand
    brand = container.div.div.a.img["title"]
    
     #scrape the product name
    title = container.findAll("a", {"class":"item-title"})
    product_name= title[0].text 
    
     #scrape the shipping
    shipping_container= container.findAll("li", {"class":"price-ship"})
    shipping = shipping_container[0].text.strip()
    
    #scrape price
    pricec = container.find("li", {"class":"price-current"})
    #removing all white spaces from price
    price= pricec.text.strip('price-current')
    
    
    d['Product'].append(product_name)
    d['shipping'].append(shipping)
    d1['Product'].append(product_name)
    d1['Brand'].append(brand)
    d1['price'].append(price)
    
    
# create dataframe using pandas feature
df = pd.DataFrame(d) #product and shipping
df1 =pd.DataFrame(d1) #product, brand and price


# clean shipping column
df['shipping'] = df['shipping'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == 'Free Shipping' else x)

#cleaning price column
df1['price'] = df1['price'].str.extract('(\d+\.?\d+)').astype(float)

#string converted to float
df['shipping'] = df['shipping'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == 'Special Shipping' else x) # probably should be handled in a special way
df['shipping'] = df['shipping'].apply(lambda x: x if x == 0 else re.sub("[^0-9]", "", x))
df['shipping'] = df['shipping'].astype(float)

# save dataframe to csv files
df.to_csv('dataframe.csv', index=False)
df1.to_csv('dataframe1.csv', index=False)```
````

Comment: here is what I got so far but it only give me the name of the file. what argument should I pass?                                                                                                                                         def longest_word(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
              words = infile.read().split()
    max_len = len(max(words, key=len))
    return [word for word in words if len(word) == max_len]

print(longest_word('dataframe2.csv'))

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer without seeing your dataframe (see [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for tips). But hopefully the following will give you some ideas, using a dummy df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a','bb','ccccc','dd']})
df
```

this is our dataframe we want to sort by the length of `'name'`:

```
    name
0   a
1   bb
2   ccccc
3   dd
```

We can do the following (apply `len` function to each element of `'name'` and use that for sorting

```
df.sort_values('name',key = lambda c : c.apply(len))
```

prints

```
    name
0   a
1   bb
3   dd
2   ccccc
```

Comment: This is how my dataframe looks like but this is just the first two line so it keeps going with different values:                                  Product,shipping,Brand,price
The Last of Us Part II - PlayStation 4,0.0,PlayStation,59.99

Comment: @XavierValdez so the above should work if you replace `'name'` with `'Product'` -- does it for you?